# Words inside <a> are overflow, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css

This is a part of my HTML code:

```
<div id="content" class="row">
       <div id="tab1" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div id="login-title" class="panel-heading"> Customer Login </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal" action="index.html" method="post" role="form">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="label_login">Login Name:</label>
             <input id="input_login" type="text" name="user_name" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Login Name.">
             <label class="label_login">Password:</label>
             <input id="input_login" type="password" name="user_password" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enetr the Password.">
             <button id="btn_login" type="login" name="btn">Login</button>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div id="login-title" class="panel-heading"> Company News </div>
         <div class="news">
           <h2> Aug 12, 2016 </h2>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"> ...</a>
           <h2> Jun 23, 2016 </h2>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">...</a>
           <h2> Dec 06, 2015 </h2>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">...</a>
           <h2> Oct 10, 2014 </h2>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">...</a>
           <h2> Jul 22, 2014 </h2>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">...</a>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
     Main
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the result I get:
[image]

It's obviously that the words are overflowed.
I tried `width` and `overflow` (in `.news a`)but they didn't work...
What's wrong??

Comment: `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: You might want to try applying those properties to the `div` itself, not the `a` tag ... that aside, is the whole link necessary for your client? Could you just shorten the URL, or grab the `<title>` from the link and display that instead?

Comment: Could you please give me a demo instead of photo?

Comment: Joseph Young got the right answer. It's because it can't wrap long words/urls so you need to force it with word-break

Comment: @JosephYoung Thank u so much! You perfectly solve my trouble~

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 (short, if you do not care hiding some parts of the URLs):

```
.news a {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Solution 2 (short, if you do not care hiding some parts of the URLs):

```
.news {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**Solution 3:**

```
.news a {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* legacy version */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `white-space: nowrap;` then change its property to "normal", i guess it will solve your problem, please give me a demo link instead of image so that i can sort out.

Answer (score 0):

To cover all browsers, you can use this:

```
.news a {
    hyphens: auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```